# How to break down 「北航路」?

Tags: words

In a sentence

> もう、何度目の北航路になるだろう

I break down 北航路 as 北{きた} + 航路{こうろ} ("north course", based on a previous context where words were used separately).  But would it also make sense (perhaps in some other context) to break it down as 北航{ほっこう} + 路{じ} (something like "north-sailing route")?  Or does such split makes no sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hadn't heard the word 北航 but 北航する seems to be used in  specialized book of ship. However I think 北航路 can't be separated as 北航 + 路 because 北航 isn't common word.

北航路 can commonly be separated as 北 + 航路 as you know.

Comment: Hmm, indeed, the word 北航 is present in [bilingual](http://jisho.org/search/%20%E5%8C%97%E8%88%AA) dictionary, but I failed to find it in a few monolingual dictionaries I just tried.  Thanks!

Comment: I found out 北航する in specialized book of ship but it isn't common word.